# И снова оборот с союзом как

Tags: пунктуация

Заинтересовало, нужна ли здесь запятая или запятые? И по какому правилу? Указательного слова здесь нет, но есть местоимение "которой". Это играет роль? Или тут все зависит от оборота "как обязательного условия поставки продукции"? И кстати, какую функцию он здесь выполняет?

…наличия которой как обязательного условия поставки продукции требует целый ряд организаций…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, это не сравнительный оборот. В качестве обязательного условия.